# std::shared_ptr templated vs. non-templated copy/move constructors

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, shared-ptr

[This page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr) shows that `std::shared_ptr` has a templated and a non-templated version of copy/move constructors ((9) and (10) on the page). Similarly, it also has two versions of copy/move assignment operator (see [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/operator%3D)).

Why do we need the non-templated version? Wouldn't the templated version alone suffice?

Comment: A template is never(!) a copy/move constructor

Comment: @DieterLücking If we delete the (non-templated) copy/move constructors, what kind of code will break?

Comment: ... without the non template constructors default constructors might get generated (if possible).

Comment: @DieterLücking however, it can "hide" the copy/move constructor (e.g. when copy from a non-const lvalue).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The templated version is not a copy constructor. According to the standard §12.8[class.copy]/2 we have that:

> A non-template constructor for class X is a copy constructor if its first parameter is of type X&, const X&, volatile X& or const volatile X&, and either there are no other parameters or else all other parameters have default arguments (8.3.6).

And similarly, the templated version is also not a copy assignment operator, according to §12.8[class.copy]/17:

> A user-declared copy assignment operator X::operator= is a non-static non-template member function of class X with exactly one parameter of type X, X&, const X&, volatile X& or const volatile X&.

The same holds true for move constructors (at §12.8[class.copy]/3):

> A non-template constructor for class X is a move constructor if its first parameter is of type X&&, const X&&, volatile X&&, or const volatile X&&, and either there are no other parameters or else all other parameters have default arguments (8.3.6).

and move assignment operators, at §12.8[class.copy]/19:

> A user-declared move assignment operator X::operator= is a non-static non-template member function of class X with exactly one parameter of type X&&, const X&&, volatile X&&, or const volatile X&&.

Comment: How about the assignment operators?